# Hide a table column using jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am trying to hide a table column of a table with jQuery but am not really sure on how to do it. I have a drop down for each column and have two options, hide and show, on hide I would like column 0 to be hidden using the `.hide()` function I presume, and also shown when show is selected?

Comment: Are the drop-downs for show/hide inside the columns themselves? Could you show us the code you're using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) pseudo-selector selects elements based on their position. If you want to select the, say, 5th column, you can use `$("td:nth-child(5)")`.

An implementation could look like:

```
$("#mytable td:nth-child(5)").hide(); //or .hide(), or .toggle()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, will this unhide the column too if I put this on the show action too ?.  thanks :-)

Comment: If you replace `hide` with `show`, the columns will show. *Extra*: If you replace `hide` with `toggle`, the columns will show if they're hidden, and hide when they're visible;

Comment: Actually this will only hide the fifth td in the entire table, not the fifth one in each row. Not sure if `$("#mytable tr td:nth-child(5)")` would work or if you need to use `each()` on the `tr`s.

Comment: @Purmou Simplified demo to prove the opposite **: http://jsfiddle.net/ELRpv/**. EDIT: Explanation of the `:nth-child` pseudo-selector: It selects element based on their position, relative to their siblings. Note that the type of the element doesn't matter (`a:nth-child(2)` on `<br/><br/><a>` is equivalent to `<q/><q/><a>`).

Comment: @RobW: Ah yes, I was thinking in terms of `eq()`. This selects every second `td`.

Comment: Here's a sample with the `toggle()` functionality. It was going to be my answer, but @RobW beat me to the punch ;) http://jsfiddle.net/htd7r/

Answer (score 1):

```
var $col_select = $('#col-select'),
    $opt_select = $('#opt-select'),
    $my_table   = $('table');
$col_select.add($opt_select).on('change', function () {
    var col_val = $col_select.children(':selected').val(),
        opt_val = $opt_select.children(':selected').val();
    if (col_val !== '' && opt_val !== '') {
        $my_table.find('td:nth-child(' + col_val + ')').css('display', opt_val);
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RjXpq/2/

Comment: That loop is not very efficient. 1) The value of `col_select` will not modify during the execution. So, it's better to cache the value. 2) `:nth-child` can also be used directly on the `td` selector, which eliminates the need for `.each()`.

Comment: @RobW Good call on the loop, here is a definition of `not very efficient`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-tr-vs-td-selector (answer updated)